# Why is this function smooth on the coordinate axis

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider the function

$$f(x,y):=\sqrt{x^2+xy+y^3}, \quad x,y \geq 0.$$

It is claimed that this function is smooth except at the origin. I am wondering why this function is not smooth at (0,0) in the sense that there is no smooth extension $\tilde{f}:B_{\epsilon}(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of f on some open ball around the origin.

Obviously $f$ would not be smooth if we would use the above formula for an extension around $(0,0).$ But why can't there be any different smooth extension?

Best wishes

Comment: You defined $f$ only for $x,y>0$ so how can we talk about its behaviour on the axes (where $x=0$ or $y=0$)? Or did you mean $x,y\geq 0$?

Comment: You should change it better. Use the given formula for $x,y\ge 0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $f$ is positive at each point of the positive $x$ and $y$ axes.

---

Added hint for the new question:

If you consider $f(x,0),f(0,y)$ for $x,y>0,$ you'll find the one sided partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are $1$ and $0$ respectively. Is it true that $[f(x,x)-f(0,0)]/x \to \nabla f(0,0)\cdot (1,1)$ as $x\to 0^+?$ That would be true if $f$ were smooth in a neighborhood of $(0,0).$

Comment: Thank you! This was really easy. Do you have another hint, why this function can not be extended smoothly in the origin?